# If $a_n > 0$ and $\lim (a_n) ^{1/ n} = L<1$, then $a_n <r^n$ for some $r<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that for every $n \in N, a_n > 0$, that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = L,$$
and that $L < 1$. Prove that there exists $r < 1$ such that for $n$ suﬃciently large, $0 ≤ a_n < r^n$.

This one is slightly confusing because $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = 1$ since $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n} = 0$ So I don't see why $L < 1$

The other part makes some sense. since let $a_n > 0$ and take $(-(a_n + 1))^n, n \in 2\mathbb{Z}^{+}, -(a_n+1) < 1$ and $0 \le a_n < (-(a_n+1))^n$

Comment: Why do you think $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = 1$$ Consider the sequence $a_n = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$.

Comment: ah thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Choose $r$ halfway between $L$ and $1$. After a while, $a_n^{1/n}\lt r$.

**Added:** The above is essentially a full proof, but we give additional detail.

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1-L}{2}$. Then there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$, then 
$$|a_n^{1/n}-L|\lt \epsilon= \frac{1-L}{2}.$$
Since $a_n\gt 0$, we have for $n\gt N$ that
$$0\lt a_n^{1/n}\lt L+\frac{1-L}{2}=\frac{1+L}{2}=r.$$
Thus if $n\gt N$ then $0\lt a_n\lt r^n$.

Comment: let $r = \frac{L+1}{2}$, and knowing since $(a_n)^{1/n} \to L$ then $|a_n| \to |L|$

So for sufficiently large $N$, then $2(|(a_n)^{1/n})| - |L| ) < 1 \to 2|(a_n)^{1/n}| < |L|+1 \to |(a_n)^{1/n} < \frac{1+L}{2} < 1 \to 0 \le |((a_n)^{1/n})^{n}| < (\frac{1+L}{2})^n$

Comment: Everything is $\ge 0$, absolute value signs are not needed. And what you have written is far too complicated, and I really don't want to check whether it is right. I will give the full formal proof in an addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not.  Then for each $r <1$, there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ (denoted again by $a_n$) such that $a_n >r^n$.  Taking the $\frac{1}{n}$ powers gives $(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} >r$.  Now, if we choose $r >L$, we have that in the limit, $L > r > L$ .